# Google Dataflow: PCollection<String> to PCollection<TableRow> for BigQuery insertion

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm fairly new to the Google Cloud Platform and I'm trying Google Dataflow for the first time for a project for my postgraduate programme. What I want to do is write an automated load job that loads files from a certain bucket on my Cloud Storage and inserts the data from it into a BigQuery table.

I get the data as a `PCollection<String>` type, but for insertion in BigQuery I apparently need to transform it to a `PCollection<TableRow>` type. So far I haven't found a solid answer to do this.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Defining the schema of the BigQuery table
    List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("Datetime").setType("TIMESTAMP"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("Consumption").setType("FLOAT"));
    fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("MeterID").setType("STRING"));
    TableSchema schema = new TableSchema().setFields(fields);

    //Creating the pipeline
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    //Getting the data from cloud storage
    PCollection<String> lines = p.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadCSVFromCloudStorage").from("gs://mybucket/myfolder/certainCSVfile.csv"));

    //Probably need to do some transform here ...

    //Inserting data into BigQuery
    lines.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
            .named("WriteToBigQuery")
            .to("projectID:datasetID:tableID")
            .withSchema(schema)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
}
```

I'm probably just forgetting something basic, so I hope you guys can help me with this ...

Comment: You should refer to https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do - this shows how to transform a `PCollection<String>` using ParDo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BigQueryIO.Write` operates on `PCollection<TableRow>`, as outlined in [Writing to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/bigquery-io#writing).  You'll need to apply a transform to convert `PCollection<TableRow>`into `PCollection<String>`.  For an example, take a look at [StringToRowConverter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/StreamingWordExtract.java#L88):

```
  static class StringToRowConverter extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {
    /**
     * In this example, put the whole string into single BigQuery field.
     */
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      c.output(new TableRow().set("string_field", c.element()));
    }
  ...
}
```